# excel find the value and replace the value of another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wanted to ask someone who is an expert in Excel.
I have attached an image, What I want is to find all cells with the value "CLAY" and replace the value of "0" to "100" in column G.

[image]

Comment: if you need this to be done directly in column G without the use of a helper column, try `vba` (add it to your tags so someone can assist you). However I would prefer the simplicity of using a helper column ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the G Column, input the following formula:

```
=if($F1="CLAY", 100, 0)
```

You may need to change `F1` to whichever row you are on, then just drag it down.

Also, as I'm unsure whether or not the adjacent data is relevant, it might be beneficial to sort and filter the data first so as not to overwrite the other data already present.

Comment: Hi, I have also tried your formula =IF($F1:$F23="CLAY",999,0)  if the value is clay change it into 999 if value is false change it into "0" but not all value i must change into "0" is there a possible to make the false value into "nochange" meaning whatever the value is in there, it will not change into 0

Comment: @pryde1919 No, you would need to use a helper column to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your column F have other material name, also with value 0 in column G

The target is for the named of "CLAY", replace the value of "0" into "100"only,  and the other values remain the same values.

Try, the use of "Conditional formatting" way.

Select `G1:G100` (or to end cell of your column G data) >> `Conditional Formatting` >> `New rule`>> select "`Use a formula`…." >>

'>> In the rule box enter : `=F1="CLAY"` >>

'>> Click "`Format`" >> choose, "`Number`" tab >> click "`Custom`" >>

'>> In the window box enter : `0;0;100` >> OK

'>> Finish

Comment: an interesting approach but the result only "looks like" `100` but it is actually `0` which might be misleading if OP needs to literately increase the value of `0` to `100`.

Comment: You are correct, the way purpose is "not to affect the other values (include 0 value of the other names) in the same column". Otherwise it needs a helper column something like =IF(F1="CLAY",100,G1) or VBA

Comment: Hi bosco_yip,

I have tried your formula it works :) but there is one little problem, each clay value has different value, sometimes its not 0, sometimes the value is 92 or 87

is there a way to change all the clay value into "100" whatever the value that existed in column G?

Comment: To change all "Clay" value into 100 in existing column G, just change the Conditional Formatting - custom cell format, from 0;0;100 into "100";0;100